# How to enable the DayDream feature in the Galaxy Nexus10 Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I made android emulator for Nexus 10 using latest ADT(21) and SDK tools.

I know that in Android JellyBean 4.2 there's a new feature called DayDream. I want to access it in my Nexus10 Emulator I have. but don't know how.

i am not getting option **Daydream** inside `Settings -> Display`.

**How can i enable and use it Inside Emulator?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what i need to do:

**1st Step:** Launch the Settings app, scroll to the bottom, and tap About Phone.

**2nd Step:** In the middle of the screen is the listing for Android Version. Tap this item until you see a jelly bean appear on your screen. You can then tap and hold the giant jelly bean until your device vibrates. You should then see interactive beans floating all over your screen. And yes, you can fling them. Go ahead, try it.

**3rd Step :** After doing, this the BeanFlinger Daydream will be unlocked. You can find the Daydream option by going to Settings > Display > Daydream.

Hope it Will Help to all of the Users Facing this Same kind of Problem.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem, what I did was, previously, I had an emulator with 4.2.1 version. I changed it to 4.3, now its working for me.